# What is the name and notation of this type of distributed set complementation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I am working on a problem where I need to describe a certain type of "distributed" complementation.  Can someone suggest a name and notation for the operation I'm trying to define?  Perhaps there is already one already, in which case I'll happily use the standard name and notation.

If $U$ is a universal set and $G\subset U$.   Let $V$ be an exhaustive set of subsets of $G$ such that $G = \bigcup\limits_{v\in V}v$.  Note that $V$ is a subset of the power set of $G$,  $V\subset 2^G$. 
(1)

1. I'd like $\overline{V}$ to mean $2^G \setminus V$
2. and $V^{*}$ to mean the set of complements of the elements of $V$, $V^{*} = \{\overline{v} \mid v \in V\}$, where here $\overline{v}$ denotes $G\setminus v$.

My notation is bad.  I'd like a better one.

One problem with my notation is that $V^*$ does not indicate the set which complements are taken with respect to. E.g., using the backslash notation for set minus I can distinguish between $2^G \setminus V$ vs $2^U \setminus V$, but I can't distinguish the two types of $V^*$ where in distributed complement is taken with respect to $G$ vs $U$.

Comment: What is does it mean when you require $V$ to be "exhaustive"?

Comment: And which role does $U$ play in your construction? It looks like everything you write takes place inside $G$?

Comment: Hi Henning,  by "exhaustive set of subsets" I mean that the union of the subsets is G.   {{1,2},{2,3}} is an exhaustive set of subsets of {1,2} but it is not an exhaustive set of subsets of {1,2,3} even though {1,2} and {2,3} are indeed subsets of {1,2,3}.

Comment: What role does U play?   Its purpose is to illustrate that the the distributed complement with respect to G is different than the distributed complement with respect to U.      Sorry if that is confusing.  I originally posed the question without mentioning G, and rather always referred to the "union of V".  I thought the question might be clearer if I remove lots of occurrences of "union of V" and just referred to them as G.

Comment: I'm not sure that you _need_ a specifier in $V^*$ then. If you're only considering $V$s whose union is $G$, you can recover $G$ from $V$, so you could define $V^*=\{{\cup}V\setminus v\mid v\in V\}$ for an arbitrary set-of-sets $V$ without introducing ambiguity.

Comment: Yes it does look like that from the example here.  But in my more elaborate paper, I have cases with I have various subsets of V which are not exhaustive, and I need to talk about their distributed complements w.r.t. V.  I.e., if W is a subset of V, then I need W* to be the set of complements with respect to $\cup V,$ not with respect to $\cup W$.  I could put a subscript on the * of course, but I'm just inviting more notation.   Perhaps that's the correct thing to do?